# onListItemClick stops working after one click

Tags: android, listview, view, onclick

**LAST EDIT**
I found the problem with solution here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414#c27

**ORIGINAL POST**
I have a ListView (actually a ListFragment) where I want to expand a object when I click on it, and collaps it again on a second click.

This is my onListItemClick

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    //mAdapter.toggleItem(id); // removed this

    ListView list = getListView();
    int start = list.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    for (int i = start, j = list.getLastVisiblePosition(); i <= j; i++) {
        Cursor item = (Cursor) list.getItemAtPosition(i);
        if (id == item.getLong(item.getColumnIndex(ItemColumns._ID))) {
            View view = list.getChildAt(i - start);
            ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) view.findViewById(R.id.stub);
            // View inflated;
            if (stub.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                stub.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            else
                stub.inflate();
            // list.getAdapter().getView(i, view, list);
            // break;
        }
    }

}
```

It works, but it only fires once. Once the ListItem has expanded the onListItemClick wont get fired again. Any idea why?

best

Marcus

**EDIT:** It's the actual line: stub.inflate(); which disables the click event

**EDIT2:** I foudn the problem was due to the ViewStub

it look like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#CC0000"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <SeekBar android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The LinearLayout does not shadow the original listItem. But if I remove the seekbar it works great.

Comment: nothing - it's just some deprecated code I forgot to remove.

Answer (score 1):

If your listview contains a control that can steal the focus (Seekbar in your situation), you just need to make it not focusable

```
<SeekBar
        android:focusable="false" />
```